# Как в JavaFX-приложениях, собираемых Gradle, указать относительный путь к FXML-файлу?

Tags: java, javafx, gradle

Пытаюсь загрузить `TasksList.fxml` в классе `TasksListController`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```java
this.rootElement = new FXMLLoader(TasksListController.class.getResource("TasksList.fxml")).load();
```

Из ошибки видно, что Gradle пытается искать это в `build\resources`:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IntelliJ IDEA\Tutorials\JavaFX-ToDoList\build\resources\main\Presenter\Components\TaskList\TasksList.fxml
```

В [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531318/4818123) на англоязычном StackOverflow очень хорошо разжевано, как нужно подключать ресурсы, но увы, для Gradle этот ответ неактуален (когда Gradle нет, то `class.getResource("TasksList.fxml")` - путь относительно текущей директории с классом). Как же в Gradle достучаться до нужного файла?

Мой `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

group 'loc.training'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
  version = "13"
  modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'EntryPoint'
```

[Весь код приложения (репозиторий)](https://bitbucket.org/TokugawaYD/javafx-todolist/src/problem1/)

### Недопустимые решения

#### Поместить `TasksList.fxml` в resources

Я хочу организовать файлы по папкам покомпонентно: в каждой папке с компонентом находится его разметка, логика, стили и так далее.

Comment: мне когда-то приходилось писать приложение FX на Gradle. насколько я помню, там использовался специальный плагин... а у вас как? моете показать файл конфигурации?

Comment: @Дмитрий, благодарю Вас за отклик на мой вопрос. Конечно, я добавил конфигурацию в конец вопроса.

Comment: а какую версию градла вы используете?

Comment: @Дмитрий, хороший вопрос... Подскажите пожалуйста, какой нынче актуален способ проверки версии Gradle? Судя по всему, в `Project Structure-> Project` среды IntelliJ IDEA этой информации, как раньше, больше нет.

Comment: попробуйте взять этот ресурс из лоадера вашего Main класса

Comment: @DimaMorgunov, это как? Насколько я знаю, класс являющийся точкой входа, так просто в TasksListController не импортировать...

Comment: Если вы храните ресурсы не в ресурсах, а в коде, то попробуйте вместо `getResource()` использовать `getClassLoader().getResource()`. Не очень понятна проблема добавить папку с ресурсами в градле.

Comment: @Maxim, эффект тот же: "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IntelliJ IDEA\Tutorials\JavaFX-ToDoList\build\resources\main\Presenter\Components\TaskList\TasksList.fxml". "Не очень понятна проблема добавить папку с ресурсами в градле." - проблема проста: я, будучи новичком в Gradle, не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

- поместить `TaskCard.fxml` и `TaskList.fxml` в `src/main/resources`
- заменить в `RootLayout.fxml`:

```
<fx:include source="Presenter/Components/TaskList/TasksList.fxml" />
```

на

```
<fx:include source="TasksList.fxml" />
```

UPDATE: Другой вариант: добавить в `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
      srcDirs "src/main/resources", "src/main/java"
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE_2: Сразу оговорюсь: я не эксперт в `gradle`, практически им не пользуюсь и далее будет моя интерпретация.
`sourceSet` - наборы логически разделенных исходных файлов (код, ресурсы, зависимости), где по умолчанию уже присутствуют `main` и `test` с фильтрами по расширению (например включение только `**/*.java` для `src/main/java`). Чаще всего используется для разделения различных этапов тестирования (юнит-тесты отдельно от интеграционных, отдельно от системных) или выставления собственных фильтров на папки\файлы; например:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
      srcDirs "src/main/resources", "src/main/java"
      // exclude '**/something/**'
      // include '**/something/**'
    }
  }
  integr_test {
    java {
      srcDirs "src/integr_test"
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  integr_testImplementation('com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre')
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Моя вина, что я не сказал в вопросе чётко, что такое решение не допускается, а потому я присуждаю Вам награду.

Comment: @БоковГлеб Пытаюсь честно заслужить) Обновил ответ

Comment: прошу прощения за позднюю реакцию. У меня уже появилось окно Java FXML. Ошибка сменилась, но я не могу её прочесть из-за кракозябров. Это претендует на отдельный вопрос, но я уверен, что Ваше решение сработало. Могу я Вас попросить дать краткий комментарий по поводу Вашего решения? И на этом закроем вопрос; дам Вам ещё одну награду.

Comment: @БоковГлеб Обновил ответ, это максимум который я смог из себя выжать

Comment: Какое счастье что я могу отблагодарить Вас не только словом "спасибо", но и очками репутации!